# SQL Server : using Or - And

Tags: sql-server

```
WHERE CompanyId=@CompanyId
or
P.ProductId=1
or
C.CustomerSituation=1
```

If `CompanyId` must be like below (required)

I want something like below.

```
Where

AND CompanyId=@CompanyId // Question here

Or P.ProductId=1
Or C.CustomerSituation=1
```

`CompanyId` must be and(required %100) other values are or.

How can I give "and" for `CompanyId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Where
CompanyId=@CompanyId // Question here
AND
(P.ProductId=1 OR C.CustomerSituation=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use brackets to specify priority

```
Where

CompanyId=@CompanyId // Question here
AND (
   Or P.ProductId=1
   Or C.CustomerSituation=1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm only 40% sure what you're asking here; I'll assume, that exact string `AND CompanyId=@CompanyId` must appear in the query, because you're building dynamic query generated from a web page, or something.

```
Where 1=1
    and CompanyId=@CompanyId
    and (1=2
        Or P.ProductId=1
        Or C.CustomerSituation=1
    )
```